# How to make the statue of liberty dancing?

Tags: software-recommendation

1. How did they made [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZqu8ojifhU)? For example, what did they use to make the statue of liberty dancing?
2. What *you* would use to achieve such a result?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: it's quite a broad question, and you're essentially asking for a tutorial, hence the downvotes. Check [ask] to get a better idea of what kind of questions get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any 3D animation tool + camera matchmove and compositioning. So any of:

   - 3DS Max
   - Blender
   - Cinema 4D
   - Maya
   - Modo
   - ...

   Plus one of:

   - After effects
   - Digital fusion
   - Nuke
   - ...

   Alternatively you may want a sculpting application.
2. Depends on what tools i am given by my company to use. But this is generally not a one person job. You would likely want atleast 3 or 4 different professions for this.

Comment: How long would you guess it takes to make the full video?

Comment: Well you can roughly calculate 1 hour per second of output. So about 100 hours of work. But if you buy the models ready rigged and because there is lower quality sequences maybe 50-60 hours. But this assumes you know what your doing.

Comment: I mean, how does it work? Do you need a 3D model of the statue of liberty? Did they took then a video of the real statue of liberty, removed her and substituted her with the 3D model?

Comment: @raffaem Yes you need a 3D model thats one way of getting one. You either model and rig, texrure and animate or then you buy it ready made and only animate. This part is usually a job for 2 people with different skills